# std::map::at returns warning "returning reference to temporary" somewhere in the call stack

Tags: c++, c++11

I am looking up the value of a key from a `std::map`.  I get the following error inside Dataset::getProperty():

`returning reference to temporary [-Wreturn-local-addr]`

Where in the call stack is the temporary created?  I thought `std::map::at` returned a reference to an lvalue, and because I continously return `reference-to-const` that the original caller would have a reference to the lvalue.

**Dataset**

```
class Dataset
{
  private:
    PropertyCollection properties;

  public:
    const std::string & getProperty(const std::string & key) const;

  ...
}

const std::string & Dataset::getProperty(const std::string & key) const
{
  // WARNING: returning reference to temporary [-Wreturn-local-addr]
  return properties.getProperty(key);
}
```

**PropertyCollection**

```
class PropertyCollection
{
  private:
    std::map<std::string, std::string> properties;

  public:
    const bmd2::string & getProperty(const bmd2::string & key) const

  ...
}

const std::string & PropertyCollection::getProperty(const std::string & key) 
      const
{
  try {
    return properties.at(key);
  } catch (std::out_of_range & e) {
    ...
  }
```

**Main**

```
int main() {
  ...
  std::string key ("Cats");
  std::string value = dataset.getProperty(key);
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`getProperty` returns a `bmd2::string` not a `std::string`. Thus a `std::string` must be implicitely constructed/converted from a `bmd2::string`. This `std::string` is then of course a new temporary object.

While its actually not illegal to return a reference to a temporary, using such a reference (if out of scope) will result in UB, thus the compiler warns you.

Comment: The assumption is that `bmd2::string` and `std::string` are not the same type, I suppose.

Comment: Ah, the implicit conversion!  Yes, they are NOT the same type.  Thank you for catching this Paranaix.